# Subtracting floating points using awk

Tags: bash, awk, floating-point

I have a bash script which subtracts 0.0001 from larger numbers with awk. It is not working when numbers have more than four decimal places.

It uses these arguments to awk...

```
balance=$(awk -vn1="$balance" -vn2="0.0001" 'BEGIN{print (n1-n2) }')
```

If `$balance` equals `1.44189949` the number ends up `1.4418` and it needs to be `1.44179949` so I've done something wrong.

I have never dealt with floating point numbers in bash before.

Comment: seems like awk rounds the result.

Comment: It's not working. `fatal: not enough arguments to satisfy format string` I tried: `balance=$(awk -vn1="$balance" -vn2="0.0001" 'BEGIN{printf("12.8%f" (n1-n2))}')`

Comment: There was a missing comma but now I get very strange output: `12.81.441799`

Comment: YOu want `%.8f` not `12.8%f`

Comment: The format for numbers should be governed by the variable `OFMT`. Hence `awk -vn1="$balance" -vn2="0.0001" -vOFMT="%.10g" 'BEGIN{ print n1-n2 }'` should do. The default for `OFMT` is `%.6g`, that's why your results seemed to be truncated.

Comment: When it got that long to do a simple calculation I looked into finding something else to do it. It seems `bc` is better than `awk` for this.

Comment: I love bc, but its string manipulation facilities are very limited. Also, arbitrary precision arithmetic is slower than hardware-supported floating-point arithmetic. So unless you need more precision than the 15 or so digits that you get using awk (or any other language that uses IEEE 754 double-precision floating-point) I recommend using awk rather than bc.

Comment: Also, as BMW mentions bc is not always available, whereas some flavour of awk almost always is. OTOH a system that doesn't have bc might have the older dc, which uses [RPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using printf and change the default rounding behaviour of awk by using     `"%.8f\n"` for eight rounding figures.

```
awk  -vn1="1.44189949" -vn2="0.0001" 'BEGIN{printf ("%.8f\n",n1-n2)}'
```

Comment: This truncates the 1 at the start with result: `0.44179949`

Comment: I removed the "$" from "$1.44189949" which caused the truncation. results should be good

Answer (score 2):

Just set OFMT you want and print the result, no need for printf:

```
$ awk -v n1="1.44189949" -v n2="0.0001" -v OFMT="%.8f" 'BEGIN{print n1-n2}'
1.44179949
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use `bc` rather than `awk` to do this calculation.

```
balance=$(echo $balance-0.0001 | /usr/bin/bc)
```

The best solution to a problem is usually the easiest one.

Comment: `bc` does decimal math. Most other languages (including C++, PHP and awk) do math in binary. (There are proposals to add decimal floating point to C and C++, and a partial implementation is available as a GCC extension.)

Comment: bc is not always installed by default in some unix system.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish, you may dispense with `awk` as I did in the following bash script:

```
balance=1.44189949
printf "%.8f\n" $(bc -l <<< "$balance - 0.0001")
```

This code utilizes `bc` which is most adept at handling floating point values. Then `printf` takes care of rounding it so the result is:

```
1.44179949
```

Note that the input for `bc` is a [here string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings) that gets redirected to the command.